# Substring Method in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have Textboxes Lines:

```
{ LstScan = 1,100, DrwR2 = 0000000043 }
{ LstScan = 2,200, DrwR2 = 0000000041 }
{ LstScan = 3,300, DrwR2 = 0000000037 }
```

I should display:

```
1,100
2,200
3,300
```

this is a code that I can't bring to a working stage.

```
 Dim data As String = TextBox1.Lines(0)
    ' Part 1: get the index of a separator with IndexOf.
    Dim separator As String = "{ LstScan ="
    Dim separatorIndex = data.IndexOf(separator)
    ' Part 2: see if separator exists.
    ' ... Get the following part with Substring.
    If separatorIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim value As String = data.Substring(separatorIndex + separator.Length)
        TextBox2.AppendText(vbCrLf & value)
    End If
```

Display as follows:

```
1,100, DrwR2 = 0000000043 }
```

Comment: Substring has an overload where you specify the length.  If that pattern always persists you can do data.Substring(separatorIndex + separator.Length, 5)

Comment: You might be much better off using one of the built-in JSON parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Function ParseLine(input As String) As String
    Const startKey As String = "LstScan = "
    Const stopKey  As String = ", "

    Dim startIndex As String = input.IndexOf(startKey)
    Dim length As String = input.IndexOf(stopKey) - startIndex
    Return input.SubString(startIndex, length)
End Function

TextBox2.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, TextBox1.Lines.Select(AddressOf ParseLine))
```

If I wanted, I could turn that entire thing into a single (messy) line... but this is more readable. If I'm not confident every line in the textbox will match that format, I can also insert a `Where()` just before the `Select()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're using the version of substring that takes from the start index to the end of the string:

```
"hello world".Substring(3) 'take from 4th character to end of string
```

> lo world

Use the version of substring that takes another number for the length to cut:

```
"hello world".Substring(3, 5) 'take 5 chars starting from 4th char
```

> lo wo

If your string will vary in length that needs extracting you'll have to run another search (for example, searching for the first occurrence of `,`  after the start character, and subtracting the start index from the newly found index)

---

Actually, I'd probably use Split for this, because it's clean and easy to read:

```
 Dim data As String = TextBox1.Lines(0)
 Dim arr = data.Split() 
 Dim thing = arr(3)
```

`thing` now contains `1,100,` and you can use `TrimEnd(","c)` to remove the final comma

```
 thing = thing.TrimEnd(","c)
```

You can reduce it to a one-liner:

```
TextBox1.Lines(0).Split()(3).TrimEnd(","c)
```